# Analytic expression for a transformed function

Tags: exponential-function, matlab, change-of-variable

In MATLAB, I plotted an exponential distribution (p.d.f.) in time $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ but set the $x$ and $y$ axes to logarithmic. The plot looks like below. [image]

I'm trying to mathematically find the equation of the curve. I thought setting the $x$ axis to log would obey the transformation $t\rightarrow log(t)$ and setting the $y$ axis to log would just be applying the log to the resulting function. But that was not it - I plotted the resulting function on normal axes to verify.

Can you please help me get the equation of the curve.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the 'equation of the curve'. Aren't you plotting that equation already?

Comment: I meant what equation when plotted on linear $x$ and $y$ axes looks like the curve in the figure above, up to a proportionality constant.

Comment: I see, in this case @Harry49 already gave you the answer. Just plot 

$$
f(t) = \log\lambda - \frac{\lambda}{\ln 10}10^t
$$

on a linear scale

Answer (score 0):

One has
\begin{aligned}
\log \left(\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\right) &= \log\lambda + \frac{\ln e^{-\lambda t}}{\ln 10} \\
&= \log\lambda - \frac{\lambda t}{\ln 10} \\
& = \log\lambda -\frac{\lambda}{\ln 10} 10^{\log t}
\end{aligned}
The dependence of $\log \left(\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\right)$ with respect to $\log t$ is exponential. However, $\log \left(\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\right)$ is linear with respect to $t$.